# Responsive 3-Column-Layout, with a right column set to min-width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to have a responsive layout which behaves like this:

- BIG SCREEN (*left* and *right* div bigger than 250px):The *content* div should be centered between the *left* and the *right* div.
- SMALL SCREEN: The *right* div should have a minimum width of 250px. The *left* div should collapse first, then the *content* div.

To illustrate what I mean, here some viewport sizes (the numbers don't matter - I just want to demonstrate the behavior I want) and the corresponding sizes of the *left*, *content* and *right* divs.

**Viewport = 1600px**

300px | 1000px | 300px

**Viewport = 1500px**

250px | 1000px | 250px

**Viewport = 1400px**

150px | 1000px | 250px

**Viewport = 1250px**

0px | 1000px | 250px

**Viewport = 1000px**

0px | 750px | 250px

I have no idea how to accomplish this. I'm stuck here:

## HTML

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

## CSS

```
body {
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

div#left {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

div#content {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 60%;
  min-width:300px;
  height: 100%;
}

div#right {
  background: #ccc;
  width:20%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to change to different percentages at different screen sizes, and tweak it so they never dip below the width you want (in pixels).

**Viewport = 1600px**
25% | 50% | 25%

**Viewport = 1500px**
20% | 60% | 20%

**Viewport = 1400px**
20% | 55% | 25%

**Viewport = 1250px**
display:none | 80% | 20%

**Viewport = 1000px**
display:none | 75% | 25%

If you want *some* columns to stay at a fixed size and others fluid at certain points, that will be much more complicated. You'll need to have parent divs with padding equal to width of child columns, and then use negative margin to move the columns into the parent's padding.

Answer (score 0):

Holy grail technique (http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)

```css
*, *:before, *:after{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.column {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding:20px;
}

.wrapper{
  min-width:550px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:250px;  
}

.left{
  display:none; 
    background:yellow;
    margin-left: -100%;    
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1250px) {
   .wrapper{
    margin-left:150px;
  }   
  .left{
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    right: 150px;
  }  
}

.content{
  width:100%;
  background:green;  
}

.right{
  background:red;
  width:250px;
  margin-right: -250px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
   .wrapper{
    margin-left:250px;
  }   
  .left{
    width:250px;
    right: 250px;
  }  
}



@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
   .wrapper{
    margin-left:300px;
  }   
  .left{
    width:300px;
    right: 300px;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
  <div class="content column">content</div>
  <div class="left column">Left</div>
  <div class="right column">Right</div>
</div>
```

If you don't mind about older browser compatibility you could also try with flexbox